# Chrome extension - Is it possible to deploy a private extension?

Tags: google-chrome, plugins, devops, private

I've recently published an extension in the chrome web store with a private visibility, and it is now available to my testers for download.

Now I am trying to see if it is possible to deploy this extension programmatically mainly on Windows corporate infrastructure, either through a script or GPO.

One such script I stumbled upon is below: ( [Link](https://www.nielskok.tech/microsoft365/chrome-extension-via-win32app-in-intune/) to the original article )

```
$KeyPath = "HKLM:\Software\Policies\Google\Chrome\ExtensionInstallForcelist"
$KeyName = "1"
$KeyType = "String"
$KeyValue = "ppnbnpeolgkicgegkbkbjmhlideopiji;https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx"
#Verify if the registry path already exists
if(!(Test-Path $KeyPath)) {
    try {
        #Create registry path
        New-Item -Path $KeyPath -ItemType RegistryKey -Force -ErrorAction Stop
    }
    catch {
        Write-Output "FAILED to create the registry path"
    }
}
#Verify if the registry key already exists
if(!((Get-ItemProperty $KeyPath).$KeyName)) {
    try {
        #Create registry key 
        New-ItemProperty -Path $KeyPath -Name $KeyName -PropertyType $KeyType -Value $KeyValue
    }
    catch {
        Write-Output "FAILED to create the registry key"
    }
}
```

So the `$KeyValue = "ppnbnpeolgkicgegkbkbjmhlideopiji;https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx"` dictates the update/install location for the crx extension file.

However in this case my extension is private, so I would not expect the script / system to reach this url unless provided some way to authenticate with one of the allowed tester google accounts.

I wonder if there exist a flow for this, or if it's just plain impossible ?